# Prevent HTML error content in Azure Web Logs

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, error-logging

my Azure WebApp logs are getting html error page content.

This makes life difficult when trying to read the logs as they stream in the portal viewer.

Anyone successfully DISABLED this html error logging?

Thx.

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, do you mean you don't want to see the error page html content in log-stream like this?

[image]

As far as I know, if you enable the Diagnostics logs' detailed error message feature, it will auto collect the details error message page in your file system.

The log-stream will auto get these content and show it in the log-stream console.

If you don't want to see these error contents, you could disable detailed error message feature. It will not show the details error content in the log stream console.

[image]